Parameters for dataset and data-aware scheduling in Airflow
Has anyone had issues with their DAG having tasks not complete when passing default_args to the consumer dag?
Producer DAG Upstream:
from airflow.datasets import Dataset
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

MY_DATA = Dataset('bigquery://my-project-name/my-schema/-my-table')

data_set_operator = EmptyOperator(
    task_id="producer",
    outlets = MY_DATA
)


default_args = {
    "start_date": (2024,11,20),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "on_failure_callback": some_function
}

with DAG as (
    dag_id = "my_dag",
    max_active_runs = 1
    default_args = default_dags,
    schedule_interval = "30 8 * * *",
) as dag:

    sql_task = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id = task_id
        query = "my_query"
        conn_id = "bq_conn_id"
       params = my_dictionary
    )

    sql_task >> data_set_operator 


Consumer DAG Downstream
from airflow.datasets import Dataset
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

MY_DATA = Dataset('bigquery://my-project-name/my-schema/-my-table')

default_args = {
    "start_date": (2024,11,20),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "on_failure_callback": some_function
}

with DAG as (
    dag_id = "my_dag",
    max_active_runs = 1
    # if I comment out default args the dag works.
    default_args = default_dags,
    schedule = MY_DATA
) as dag:

    sql_task = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id = task_id
        query = "my_query2"
        conn_id = "bq_conn_id"
        params = my_dictionary2
    )


When the producer dag completes, the downstream has a completed run, but the actual task doesn't run, and task is blank/missing or not green.  After I comment out/remove the default_args parameters from the consumer DAG, it runs accordingly and I can see the task actually run.  Can we not pass default_args into the consumer DAG?

I imagine that in your default_args, you might be passing invalid values. Specifically, the date (2024, 11, 20). Did you try the following test:
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    "start_date": datetime(2024, 11, 20),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "on_failure_callback": some_function
}

